# Full height left and right borders with no bottom border

Tags: css

I would like to have full height left and right borders in my element, but I would like to bottom border to be transparent.

I currently use this:

```
.graph {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom-color: transparent; 
}
```

but the consequence of this is that the left and right borders are missing the bottom pixel:

[image]

I would ideally like my `graph` label element to have full height borders so I don't have that ugly half pixel missing at the bottom.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Try `border-bottom-width: 0;` to remove the bottom border entirely.

Answer (score 0):

try `border-bottom: none;` *after* the general `border`setting

Answer (score 0):

Try border-bottom-style: hidden; to hide the bottom border entirely.